# Loop with Lbounds and Ubounds?

Tags: vba

My LastRowsht variable count the last row of the worksheet.
If the LastRowsht + 1 = 2 (second row in Excel) there is nothing on the cell.
After this my code divide a cell by another one but the denominator needs to change depending on the LastRowsht + 1.
My lowerbound and upperbound needs to increment by 12 each time and same with the denominator.
The probleme is there is no end of upperbound ( i have to do it until the end of worksheet) so i can't figure out how i can do this.

Can you help me make this loop ? Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
    If LastRowsht + 1 = 2 Then
           sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = ""
        Else
        If 2 < LastRowsht + 1 < 15 Then
            sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = (sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 7) / sht.Cells(2, 7)) - 1
        Else
        If 14 < LastRowsht + 1 < 27 Then
            sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = (sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 7) / sht.Cells(14, 7)) - 1
        Else
        If 26 < LastRowsht + 1 < 39 Then
            sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = (sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 7) / sht.Cells(26, 7)) - 1
        Else
        If 38 < LastRowsht + 1 < 51 Then
            sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = (sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 7) / sht.Cells(38, 7)) - 1
        End If
```

Comment: I see a pattern of cells that are 12 rows difference. Why not change the **FormulaR1C1** instead of hard fixing value? Sounds like your data consists of a few small tables one below another. Otherwise, you can calculate the (2,12,26...) by a math function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is put this:

```
If LastRowsht + 1 = 2 Then
    sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = ""
Else
    sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = (sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 7) / sht.Cells((2 + ((LastRowsht + 1 - 3) \ 12) * 12), 7)) - 1
End If
```

Note that "\" is the integer division operator.

Comment: sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 17) = (sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 7) / sht.Cells((2 + ((LastRowsht+1 - 3) \ 12) * 12), 7)) - 1
I feel you meant this. (there were 1 "(" wrong and its LastRowsht+1-3)
Right?
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if the parenthesis change matters, but the LastRowSht did need the 1.  Updated either way.